# Magento capitalizes every first letter of each word of categories

Tags: magento-1.9

First of all I'm new to Magento, so I may be missing something.

I have some categories, as example:

-> Clothes and Accessories

But on the website it's displaying as Clothes And Accessories, with a capitalized A, which I don't understand why.

I checked the Magento admin and it's registered as lowercase, the database is as well stored as lowercase, and if you inspect the page it shows in lowercase as well. What may be causing it?

Images attached bellow:

Database:
[image: Database]

Website:
[image: Website]

Inspect Code:
[image: Inspect Code]

Answer (score 1):

check the CSS and looking for this

```
    text-transform: capitalize;
```